# ValueError Inconsistent number of samples error with MultinomialNB

Tags: pandas, machine-learning, scikit-learn, sklearn-pandas

I need to create a model that classifies records accurately based on a variable. For instance, if a record has predictor `A` or `B`, I want it to be classified as having predicted value `X`. The actual data  is in this form:

```
    Predicted    Predictor
      X            A
      X            B
      Y            D
      X            A
```

For my solution, I did the following:
1. Used `LabelEncoder` to create numerical values for the `Predicted` column
2. The predictor variable has multiple categories, which I parsed into individual columns using `get_dummies`.

Here is a sub-section of the dataframe with the (dummy)`Predictor` and a couple of predictor categories (pardon the misalignment):

```
    Predicted Predictor_A    Predictor_B
9056    30  0   0
2482    74  1   0
3407    56  1   0
12882   15  0   0
7988    30  0   0
13032   12  0   0
9738    28  0   0
6739    40  0   0
373 131 0   0
3030    62  0   0
8964    30  0   0
691 125 0   0
6214    41  0   0
6438    41  1   0
5060    42  0   0
3703    49  0   0
12461   16  0   0
2235    75  0   0
5107    42  0   0
4464    46  0   0
7075    39  1   0
11891   16  0   0
9190    30  0   0
8312    30  0   0
10328   24  0   0
1602    97  0   0
8804    30  0   0
8286    30  0   0
6821    40  0   0
3953    46  1
```

After reshaping the data into the datframe as shown above, I try using `MultinomialNB` from `sklearn`. When doing so, the error I run into is:

```
ValueError: Found input variables with inconsistent numbers of samples: [1, 8158]
```

I'm running into the error while trying it with a dataframe that has only 2 columns -> `Predicted` and `Predictor_A`

My questions are:

1. What do I need to do resolve the error?
2. Is my approach correct?

Comment: It isn't obvious to me what is happening with your question, let alone what the problem is.  Please read [mcve] and consider [edit]ing your question accordingly.  It is better for the community and makes it easier to answer your question.

Comment: Thank you for the feedback. I've edited the question to hopefully make it easier to understand.

Comment: @kurious which columns do you use for the model fitting ?

Answer (score 1):

- To fit the `MultinomialNB` model, you need the training samples and their features and their corresponding labels (target values).
- In your case, `Predicted` is the `target` variable and `Predictor_A  and Predictor_B` are the `features`(predictors).

---

**Example 1:**

```
from sklearn.naive_bayes import MultinomialNB
import pandas as pd
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split

df = pd.read_csv("dt.csv", delim_whitespace=True)

# X is the features
X = df[['Predictor_A','Predictor_B']]
#y is the labels or targets or classes 
y = df['Predicted']

X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size=0.33, random_state=42)

clf = MultinomialNB()
clf.fit(X_train, y_train)

clf.predict(X_test)

#array([30, 30, 30, 30, 30, 30, 30, 30, 30, 30, 30, 30, 30, 30, 30, 30, 30, 30, 30, 30, 30, 30, 30, 30, 30, 30, 30, 30, 30])

#this result makes sense if you look at X_test. all the samples are similar
print(X_test)

       Predictor_A  Predictor_B
8286             0            0
12461            0            0
6214             0            0
9190             0            0
373              0            0
3030             0            0
11891            0            0
9056             0            0
8804             0            0
6438             1            0

#get the probabilities 
clf.predict_proba(X_test)
```

**Note 2:** The data that I used can be found [here](https://files.fm/u/csaurcnb#_)

---

### EDIT

If you train the model using some documents that have let's say 4 tags(predictors), then the new document that you want to predict should also have the same number of tags.

**Example 2:**

```
clf.fit(X, y)
```

here, `X` is a `[29, 2]` array. So we have `29` training samples(documents) and its has `2` tags(predictors)

```
clf.predict(X_new)
```

here, the `X_new` could be `[n, 2]`. So we can predict the classes on `n` new documents but these new documents **should also have exactly `2` tags (predictors).**

Comment: For more context, this question pertains to document classification. The `Predicted` column has multiple categories, not continuous values. Documents have been assigned these categories manually. A document can have more than one assigned category. The `Predictor` column has auto-generated tags that are different from assigned category. A document can have multiple tags.

What I want to do is for new documents with one or more auto-generated tags, I want to predict the correct manual tag based on the tags of old documents.

Comment: So the numbers that I see in `Predicted` columns are the classes. Got it. Next, the prediction can be done as I described. You can use `clf.predict(X_new)`. Here, `X_new` is the new document and should have the same shape as the documents in `X`

Comment: Got it. I'm considering comparing MultinomialaNB, Multinomial Logistic Regression, kNN, and Neural Net to see where I get good results. Do you think the approach is reasonable?

Comment: Yes sounds okay. How many training samples do you have in total ? what is the final goal? High classification accuracy ?

Comment: I have ~12k rows when I have 1 value/cell (i.e, when I create a new row for every `Predicted` and `Predictor` value). These rows have duplicate IDs as a result. I have ~3.7k docs. 

On doing `pd.get_dummies` for `Predictor` values, I get a dataframe with `8158 rows × 186 columns`.

The data is not normally distributed if I check the freq of `Predictors`. So, some predictors have very high frequency and others are rare.

The goal is to have high degree of accuracy in classification.

Comment: Hello again. I wonder if I have set up my data correctly. As in your example, each document is being classified with `Predicted` value 30 which doesn't appear to be correct. Going back to the sample data in the question, this is what I'd expect for `Predicted` X:

P(X|A) =. P (A|X) * P (X)/P(A). Similarly, getting P(X|B). Then, if the first case has higher probability, concluding that docs with A should be tagged as X. Otherwise, docs with B should be tagged as X. Is my understanding correct?

Comment: @kurious I have edited my answer. I split the data into `train` and `test` data. Again the `X_new` documents are classified as class `30` and this makes sense in this case cause the `X_test` contains documents that are similar. In genera, If the prerformance of a classifier is not good, you need to tune the parameters, try cross-validation methods or finally, use another classifier.